# ProgressDialog does not disappear in android app

Tags: android

I have an android application which in its main activity, data are adapted from sqlite db and shown in list view. I tried to use Progress dialog to show 'loading' message to user during fetching data from db. But the dialog does not disappear.

Here is the code :

```
public class BirthdayAlarmActivity extends ListActivity {

    List<BirthdayContact> listofAvailableBirthdays;

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.birthday_list);


        listofAvailableBirthdays=new ArrayList<BirthdayContact>();

        ReinitializeList();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

        ReinitializeList();
}


void ReinitializeList()
    {

        new LoadListView().execute();

            if(listofAvailableBirthdays.size()>0)
        {
            //get ready the adapter
            ArrayAdapter<BirthdayContact> ara=
                     new                 MyArrayAdapter(BirthdayAlarmActivity.this,listofAvailableBirthdays);

            //set the adapter
            setListAdapter(ara);
             }

}

public class LoadListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

        //ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                    BirthdayAlarmActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // increment current page
                    listofAvailableBirthdays.clear();

                    listofAvailableBirthdays=BirthdayHandler.GetTenBirthDays(BirthdayAlarmActivity.this);
                }
            });
            return (null);
        }       

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // closing progress dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the point of using AsyncTask if you run all the code of doInBackground on the UI thread?

Comment: I am a newbie to the concepts like multi-threading and just learned it from this sample[http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/]. What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the technique you're using, but I'll share what works for me:

```
final ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "",
    activity.getString(R.string.please_wait), true);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try {
      --- network activity to retrieve information ---
    }
    finally {
      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          if ((progress != null) && progress.isShowing())
            progress.dismiss();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: You mean I dont need to declare  'ProgressDialog' in activty class body ?

Comment: I don't think you have to, but that's up to you.

Comment: It throws "The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}"

Comment: activity.runOnUiThread will be BirthdayAlarmActivity.this.runOnUiThread in your case, I believe. wherever I've used activity, make sure you have BirthdayAlarmActivity.this

Comment: perhaps something is throwing an exception and the ui thread code to dismiss the dialog isn't being reached. perhaps a try/finally block is what I should have included in my answer to defend against this. (edited)

Comment: It disappears, but this time the list is not being filled.

Comment: any exceptions being thrown, that you know of?

Comment: No I made breakpoints and also used try and catch and watched logcat but there was not any exception.

Comment: the filling in of the list -- is that happening asynchronously? could it be that other code is returning before the list can be filled in?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you're referring to your `pDialog` and trying to create it in a different class than the one you've declared it in.

You should try using `showDialog`, `dismissDialog` and `onCreateDialog` methods to add a layer of abstraction and that the dialog is being called in the correct class/thread. You can use a Handler aswell as an alternative.

try something like this:

```
public class BirthdayAlarmActivity extends ListActivity {

List<BirthdayContact> listofAvailableBirthdays;

ProgressDialog pDialog;
static final int LOADING_DIALOG = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.birthday_list);


    listofAvailableBirthdays=new ArrayList<BirthdayContact>();

    ReinitializeList();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    ReinitializeList();
 }


void ReinitializeList()
{

    new LoadListView().execute();

        if(listofAvailableBirthdays.size()>0)
    {
        //get ready the adapter
        ArrayAdapter<BirthdayContact> ara= 
new MyArrayAdapter(BirthdayAlarmActivity.this,listofAvailableBirthdays);

        //set the adapter
        setListAdapter(ara);
         }

 }

@Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
 {
  switch(id)
   {
     case LOADING_DIALOG:
    // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                BirthdayAlarmActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        return pDialog;

  }
}


public class LoadListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       showDialog(LOADING_DIALOG);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // increment current page
                listofAvailableBirthdays.clear();

                listofAvailableBirthdays=BirthdayHandler.GetTenBirthDays(BirthdayAlarmActivity.this);
            }
        });
        return (null);
    }       

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        dismissDialog(LOADING_DIALOG);
    }

}
```

If this fails, you should look int using messaging via the Handler class.

Comment: Thanks. I tested your sulotion, and in Hanlder when I wanted to update list view adapter, it did throw and error and told me I cant update it from another thread.